# Reverse Geocode Location: more accuracy than range

Tags: swift, location, maps, geocoding, reversegeocodelocation

I want to get a more accurate address (from coordinates) than the address range from the function

```
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {} )
```

In the google maps API guide  (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results) they specify that I can change *location_type* in order to get a more accurate address. How do I specify these parameters? This is my code:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
let location = CLLocation(latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude)
geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in ...
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the `Google Maps API`, as you linked, you need to be forming an HTTP request to the API (with an `API Key` you've acquired from Google). The `reverseGeocodeLocation` uses Apple's Map API, and is definitely not going to be able to accept Google's `location_type` parameter. The core HTTP request you're going to want to make is therefore of the form:

```
let url:String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(center.latitude),\(center.longitude)&location_type=\(DESIRED_LOCATION_TYPE)&key=\(YOUR_API_KEY)"
```

From the link you specified, the `DESIRED_LOCATION_TYPE` can be one of:

> "ROOFTOP" restricts the results to addresses for which we have
>   location information accurate down to street address precision.
>
> "RANGE_INTERPOLATED" restricts the results to those that reflect an
>   approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise
>   points (such as intersections). An interpolated range generally
>   indicates that rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.
>
> "GEOMETRIC_CENTER" restricts the results to geometric centers of a
>   location such as a polyline (for example, a street) or polygon
>   (region).
>
> "APPROXIMATE" restricts the results to those that are
>   characterized as approximate.